# Add a new tag with an event using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to add a new html tag with an event in it, for example:

```
<html ng-app="module">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="clickTest">
<div>
<input type="button" value="button1" ng-click="click($event)">
</div>
</body>
<script>
var module = angular.module("module", []);
module.controller("clickTest", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.click = function($event) {
        $($event.currentTarget.parentNode).append('<input type="button" value="button2" ng-click="click($event)">');  
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

How do I add an event in angularjs?

Comment: You could compile it. However you should really learn how to do with Angular way using directives, either custom or built-in like ngRepeat.

Comment: You should learn to embrace the "Angular Way", which is designing around your DATA rather than designing around your DOM.  You should *rarely* have to insert freeform elements in this manner.

Comment: I see, I will try to embrace the "Angular Way", I will take time to learn it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <addbuttonsbutton></addbuttonsbutton>
    <div id="space-for-buttons"></section>
</section>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.count = 0;
}

//Directive that returns an element which adds buttons on click which show an alert on click
myApp.directive("addbuttonsbutton", function(){
 return {
  restrict: "E",
  template: "<button addbuttons>Click to add buttons</button>"
 }
});

//Directive for adding buttons on click that show an alert on click
myApp.directive("addbuttons", function($compile){
 return function(scope, element, attrs){
  element.bind("click", function(){
   scope.count++;
   angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-buttons')).append($compile("<div><button class='btn btn-default' data-alert="+scope.count+">Show alert #"+scope.count+"</button></div>")(scope));
  });
 };
});

//Directive for showing an alert on click
myApp.directive("alert", function(){
 return function(scope, element, attrs){
  element.bind("click", function(){
   console.log(attrs);
   alert("This is alert #"+attrs.alert);
  });
 };
});
```

Comment: while this surely works, this is really the JQuery way of thinking, rather than the Angular way of thinking.